# HTTP method GET is not supported by this URL

Tags: java, servlets

i am having trouble with my code as i am accessing the logout servlet from a jsp page's hyperlink.

**Jsp page link:**

href="/logout"

**logout Servlet:**

```
public class logOut extends HttpServlet{

public void doGET(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp)
        throws IOException {

    resp.setContentType("text/html"); 
    System.out.println("log out servlet");
    HttpSession session = req.getSession(false);
    if (session != null) {
        session.invalidate();
    }
    resp.sendRedirect("/signin.jsp");
}
}
```

but i am having the following error :

```
HTTP ERROR 405

Problem accessing /logout. Reason:

HTTP method GET is not supported by this URL
```

please help me.....

Comment: I think method name should be doGet() instead of doGET(). (I am not sure about it)

Answer (score 10):

It is called `doGet`, not `doGET`.

The `@Override` annotation would have told you that.

Comment: +1 for mentioning @Override, would have produced a compiler error and highlighted the bug.

Answer (score 1):

Your method needs to be called

```
public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
throws ServletException, IOException { ... }
```

in order to be recognized - the uppercase letters make it fail.